# Why return None when doing recursion?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, recursion

I'm doing this problem [Add Digits](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-digits/#/description) in recursion way. Why does it return None?

```
def addDigits(num):
    """
    :type num: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    shit = str(num)
    n = len(shit)
    if n == 1:
        return num
    else:
        num = 0
        for i in xrange(n):
            num += int(shit[i])
        addDigits(num)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value of the recursive call in the last line:

```
return addDigits(num)
```

Without such a `return` you silently return `None`